# Recommended way to load .so package in tcl either statically or dynamically

Tags: package, tcl

I've an executable hosting tcl interpretor, and a library hosting a extension.
I want to be able to build the library dynamically (loaded with Tcl's `load`) 
or statically (single executable, or so loaded implicitly).

The Executable code:

```
#ifdef GO_STATIC
    extern int My_ext_Init(Tcl_Interp* interp);
    Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "my_ext", My_ext_Init, My_ext_Init);
    My_ext_Init(interp);  // THIS SHOULD NOT BE NEEDED !!
    Tcl_SetVariable(interp, "is_statically_linked", "1", TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
#else
    Tcl_SetVariable(interp, "is_statically_linked", "0", TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
#endif
```

The library Code .. can be static or dynamic library ( .a or .so / .lib or .dll ):

```
int My_ext_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
 if (Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "My_ext", "1.0") == TCL_ERROR) {
  return TCL_ERROR;
 }
 Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, /*...etc...*/);

}
```

The startup tcl code:

```
global is_statically_linked
if {$is_statically_linked} {
    load {} my_ext
} else {
    load my_ext my_ext
}
```

The problem is .. I really shouldn't be calling `My_ext_Init(interp);` as it 
should called by Tcl when I evaluate `load {} my_ext`

<sub>Made community wiki so that the recommended way can be put here.</sub>

Comment: You don't say where in the executable the first code snippet is placed. That matters quite a lot…

Answer (score 0):

Registering a “static package” is done in your application init routine, and should be done after the main interpreter is created (but obviously before you start running your scripts in it). It's a mechanism that's really designed to work the “Big Wish” method of program building, when you use `Tcl_Main()` to do the work of making an interpreter. When you're doing that, there's a callback into your code (typically called `Tcl_AppInit` though the name is actually arbitrary) that you can specify and which is the ideal place to put calls to `Tcl_StaticPackage`. The callback will be called at the right point for you to do the static package registration.

However, that's all considered rather old hat these days. A far better method is to always use dynamic libraries and to instead package everything together as a [starkit or starpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1379577/301832). The advantage with doing that is that you just need to build your `.so` files as stub-enabled (strongly recommended anyway) packages and then you include them in your VFS during the packaging process. After that, you can just do `package require` and it will all work. (Or you can locate the shared libraries in the virtual mount when running and `load` them directly.) What's even better is that you can deliver a single `.kit` file that supports multiple platforms; starpacked executables can't be quite that flexible though, as there are some natural restrictions on portability of binary executables. :-)