# How to Deploy for maked TCL Program?

Tags: deployment, tcl, installation

I'm looking For installer Program for my TCL Code.

That code included for other Program (GiD - www.gidhome.com) like a plug-in.

I haven't server or web site for distribution.

So i want to find installer for tcl codes. (Like VS studio installer or installshield).

Please introduce me installer making standalone program.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly, but maybe [starkit](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Starkit) will solve your issue? There's also a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379577/steps-to-create-a-tcl-starkit-on-a-windows-platform/1383674#1383674) on SO.

Comment: @Jerry thanks to comment, but It's not working like installer file.

Comment: I want an install wizard that can be created like "installshield"

Comment: Can you have someone improve the wording of your question, plus proof-reading? It is hard to get at the core of your question, I am afraid.

Comment: Check out https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Based+Installers for some references for actual "installers". As for "starkits" or "tclkits", there is no need for an installer, The saying goes as: "if you have the file, it is installed"!

Comment: Self answer : In my case, InstallShield is best choice. It can be select where to install, what to include, and Above all just one click to install usefully.

Comment: Do you need to write things to the registry?  If you don't, zip it up as a tarball.  To install just unzip the tarball.